# question about manipulation of gazebo gui

Tags: ros, gazebo, gui, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a simple question about the manipulation of gazebo gui: How could I make the view in the gazebo follow the model? Now the view seems to only focus on the center point of the simulated plate when gazebo starts. Also I have the similar problem with changing the view in rviz. It seems that I can only change the view according to certain point, and I can not freely change it. I use fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks in advance, Mike.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38588/question-about-manipulation-of-gazebo-gui/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would think you'd need a world plug-in. Have you checked out the [www.gazebosim.org](http://www.gazebosim.org) site? Maybe the 'Rendering' section in the api will have what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0